# How to change Map keys to Int when parsing CSV?

Tags: scala, csv, hashmap

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("src/main/Mapping.csv");
val data_map: Map[String, String] = source.getLines().map(csv=> (csv.split(",")(0),csv.split(",")(1))).toMap
```

When I get the values from my CSV file, it create a [String, String]. How do I make it [Int, String]? I've seen people say doing some thing like is suppose to work

```
val new_map = data_map.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt,v )}
```

But it doesn't seem to work becaue it throws a `NumberFormatException` error saying the first key is a string when it needs to be an Int. My map is still [String, String]. How do I make the keys integer values when I need to parse through a CSV file?

My CSV file is something simply like:

```
1,2,
3,4,
```

And so on.

Edit: Updated code to show better what the issue is. Changed it based on feedback. When I am making a new map, I get the NumberFormatExceptionError saying that it can not make a new map because the keys are Strings and I want them to be Ints.

Comment: You realize `data_map.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt,v )}` returned a new map rather thanmodifying `data_map`, yes? And that new map will have the keys as `Ints`

Comment: _"doesn't seem to be doing anything"_ what makes you say that?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I am new to Scala and when I tried to set a value to it it gives me an Initialization Error because it is saying the input value is a string instead of an int.@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Apart of the comments above, you could directly convert the string to Int when you build the Map. `map(csv=> ((csv.split(",")(0)).toInt ,csv.split(",")(1)))`

Comment: I was trying to do that but I was getting Caused by: j"ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0"" @GastónSchabas

Comment: The exception says that what you are trying to convert to Int is not an Int. `"0""` is not a number

Comment: @GastónSchabas The first key is a string value of 0. I want to turn string values to an int [String, String] -> [Int, String].

Comment: Could you provide the input you are using and the code that is failing? With a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be easier to help you

Comment: Maybe this code will help you: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/nMBAm31lQIOM8at7GTKSvw/1 It does error handling by ignoring all wrong data.

Comment: @GastónSchabas It create the [String,String] Map once it parses through the .CSV file. The code fails at `val new_map = data_map.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt,v )}`With a `NumberFormatException: For input string: "0"` Because the first key in my map is "0" -> "1". I am trying to make the new map 0 -> "1"

Answer (score 2):

The point was already made in a comment, but due to the conciseness allowed by the medium, the point might have got lost and it's worth expanding with a longer explanation.

Scala has a strong, static type system. As such, while it's technically possible, mutating the type of the value in a collection would make your code relatively awkward. On top of that, by default in Scala you use *immutable* collections, including `Map`s, which would mean that doing so is just impossible (without resorting to reflection, but you definitely do not want to go there).

The approach one would take to go from a `Map[String, String]` to a `Map[Int, String]` in a language like Scala, would be that of returning a new map altogether and use that going forward:

```
val data_map: Map[String, String] =
  source.getLines().map(csv => (csv.split(",")(0), csv.split(",")(1))).toMap

val data_map_with_int_keys: Map[Int, String] =
  data_map.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt, v) }
```

In the snippet above, `data_map` is unchanged (as it is immutable), while `data_map_with_int_keys` is the map that you want.

A few additional notes:

- while at first glance immutable data structures seem wasteful, the reality is that immutable data can be shared, meaning that, for example, under the hood the values of your map are not changed and can therefore be accessed both from the original map and the new one, reducing unnecessary copying
- you can read more mutable and immutable collections in Scala [here on the official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/overview.html)
- you can play around with the code above [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/uaDrUyqyR56KLprM7wff9g/4)
- in Scala, the tendency is normally to use `camelCase` over `snake_case`, but of course YMMV and stick to the style of the project you're in
- while it's technically not incorrect, there's no need to `csv.split` multiple times, you can do the following ([code on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/uaDrUyqyR56KLprM7wff9g/5)):

```
val data_map: Map[String, String] =
  source.getLines().map(csv => {
    val fields = csv.split(",")
    (fields(0), fields(1))
  }).toMap
```

Comment: `def createMapping: Map[Int, String] ={
    val source= scala.io.Source.fromFile("src/main/lib/Mapping.csv");
    val data_map: Map[String, String] = source.getLines().map(csv => (csv.split(",")(0), csv.split(",")(1))).toMap
    source.close();

    val data_map_with_int_keys: Map[Int, String] =
      data_map.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt, v) }

    data_map_with_int_keys
  }` I still get the error when I try to set the new map to my already created one with different values. It says NumberFormatException for input value "0". Because the first key is a string and not an integer.